# adding a css class to a html wrapping element

Tags: html

I am creating a custom CSS class and i am not sure how to write the code.

The element uses a h2 font size for its heading and a standard paragraph font size for everything else.

I would like to code a custom size for the h2 headings.

my custom class name is hosting-post-slider and my code starts as follows...

```
.hosting-post-slider {

}
```

I am not sure how to refer to the h2 heading in my CSS in the above so i can customize h2 just for this element.

Comment: something like `.hosting-post-slider h2 {}` ? Including the markup will help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for, this selects all h2 elements with your custom class

```
   h2.hosting-post-slider{
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will reference only this instance of the `h2` element. Any style you add to it will only be applied to this element.

The complete code will look like this:

```css
.hosting-post-slider h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div className="hosting-post-slider">
  <h2>My header</h2>
  <p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have some styling in a class such as

```
.hosting-post-slider {
color: red;
}
```

Then to make a single h2 tag have this style, simply do this in you HTML:

```
<h2 class="hosting-post-slider">The heading</h2>
```

If you want all h2's to have this style, either add that class to all `h2` elements, OR change your css to target all the `h2`s, such as:

```
.h2 {
color: red;
}
```